# Serial communication between python and arduino

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I am working on object tracking robot. I am using python and OpenCV to detect the object and send the proper data to the arduino that controls two servo motors.
The data which should be sent to the arduino are servo motors angles ranging between 0-180. I am using sample codes to understand how python and arduino communicate using serial bus.When I send a single digit, the arduino receives it and work as intended, but when I send more than one digit nothing happens. 
This is the arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
int data;
Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards
int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600); //initialize serial COM at 9600 baudrate
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); //make the LED pin (13) as output
  digitalWrite (LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  myservo.attach(9);
  Serial.println("Hi!, I am Arduino");
}

void loop() {
while (Serial.available()){
 //to receive more than one character 
 char buffer[] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}; // Receive up to 7 bytes
 while (!Serial.available()); // Wait for characters
 Serial.readBytesUntil('n', buffer, 7);
 data = atoi(buffer);

}
myservo.write(data);
}
```

And here is the python code:

```
import serial
import time  # Required to use delay functions

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com14', 9600)  # Create Serial port 
object called arduinoSerialData
time.sleep(2)  # wait for 2 secounds for the communication to get 
established

print arduinoSerialData.readline()  # read the serial data and print it as 
line
print ("Enter 1 to turn ON LED and 0 to turn OFF LED")

while 1:  # Do this forever

    var = raw_input()  # get input from user
    print "you entered", var  # print the intput for confirmation

    arduinoSerialData.write(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

'n' in readBytesUntil() should be '\n'.

readBytesUntil() is terminated after one byte, because the serial buffer will be empty.
If you want readBytesUntil() to read the whole serial buffer, add Serial.setTimeout(), which defaults to 1000 milliseconds to wait for data. This gives time to fill the serial buffer. 1 second is unnecessary long, but readBytesUntil() will terminate after '\n' has been found.

while (!Serial.available()); can be deleted.

Comment: I will test what you said tomorrow, but just to be clear: Won't this timeout delay the whole tracking process?

Comment: No, it will stop after the '\n', not after 1 second.